# Как сделать двойной клик назад?

Tags: java, android

У меня есть `Activity` для выхода из которого нужно имплементировать двойной клик.

`User` нажимает один раз и выскакивает информационный `pop-up`, но если `user` нажимает 2 раза то должно выполнить стандартный `onBackPeressed()`.

`Pop-up` есть, не могу только догадаться как нормально описать условие нажатия... Приходят только идеи через голову которые...

Comment: Это ещё года два назад гуглилось за 2 минуты.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
int backPressedQ = 0;

@Override
public void onBackPressed()
{
    Log.d(LOG, "onBackPressed");

            if (this.backPressedQ == 1)
            {
                this.backPressedQ = 0;
                super.onBackPressed();
            }
            else
            {
                this.backPressedQ++;
                Toast.makeText(this, "Нажмите ещё раз, чтобы выйти", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

    //Обнуление счётчика через 5 секунд
    final Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable()
    {
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            // Do something after 5s = 5000ms
            backPressedQ = 0;
            //checkNew();
        }
    }, 5000);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Добавьте счетчик, например по нечетным значениям попа по четным onBackPeressed(). использует оператор (%)

```
int counter = 0;

@Override
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
    counter++;
    if(counter%2 != 0){
        //popup
    }else {
        onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

Comment: Интересно за что кто-то минуснул

Comment: Логичнее в такой конструкции использовать булевую переменную и инвертировать ее. Так же в вопросе нужна реакция на системную кнопку назад, а не на пользовательскую.

Comment: Да, я не учел некоторые тонкости, но я просто хотел показать человеку концепцию которая поможет решить его проблему.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так

```
private static final int TIME_INTERVAL = 2000; 
private long mBackPressed;

@Override
public void onBackPressed(){
    if (mBackPressed + TIME_INTERVAL > System.currentTimeMillis()) { 
        super.onBackPressed(); 
        return;
    }
    else {
        //popup
    }
    mBackPressed = System.currentTimeMillis();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
boolean doubleClick = false;
```

На клике:

```
if(!doubleClick){
doubleClick = true;
}
else{
// Ваши действия
doubleClick = false;
}
```

на свайпах и прочих касаниях, не относящихся к клику, так же вешаем `doubleClick = false;`

Можете добавить таймер для установки флага в "ложь", если необходимо. Но последнее - уже не обязательно, особенно для обработчика на одном конкретном элементе управления.

Хотя, в Вашем случае, именно с таймером и получится решение. Если, допустим, раз в секунду проверять состояние флага "было нажатие" и флага "было двойное нажатие" и вызывать соответствующие действия.

Или запускать таймер на первом нажатии и останавливать его, если нужное условие не выполнено - до следующего события.

Comment: вместо двойного условного оператора уместнее выглядит простейшее `doubleClick = !doubleClick` - инвертирует состояние на противоположное , а условие упрощается до `if(doubleClick){ // действие }`