# Android - как реализовать двойной клик для выхода из приложения

Tags: android, double, click, backbutton

Как реализовать событие чтобы пользователь для выхода из приложения дважды кликнула на кнопку назад.

Comment: Тут есть пример https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8430805/clicking-the-back-button-twice-to-exit-an-activity/30211914

Comment: и [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/529187/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BA-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B4?rq=1)